# Using awk on a folder and adding file name to output rows

Tags: awk

I should start by thanking you all for all the work you put into the answers on this site. I have spent many hours reading through them but have not found anything fitting my question yet. Hence my own post.

I have a folder with multiple subfolders and txt-files within those. In column 7 of those files, there are gene names (I do genetics for a living :)). These are the string I am trying to extract. Shortly, I would like to search the whole folder for any rows within any of the files that contain a particular gene name/string. I have been using grep for this, writing something like:

```
grep -r GENE . > GENE.txt
```

Simple, but I need to be able to tweak the search further and it seems that then awk is the way to go.

So I tried using awk. I wrote something like this:

```
awk '$7 == "GENENAME"' FOLDER/* > GENENAME.txt
```

This works well (and now I can specify that the string has to be in a particular column, this I can not do with grep, right?).
However, in contrast to grep, which writes the file name at the start of each row, I now can not directly see which file which row in my output file comes from (which mostly defeats the point of the search). This, adding the name of the origin file somewhere to each row, seems like something that should absolutely be doable, but I am not able to figure it out.

The files I am searching within change (or rather get more numerous), but otherwise my search will always be for some specific string in column 7 of the same big folder. How can I get this working?

Thank you in advance,
Elisabet E

Comment: *adding the name of the origin file somewhere to each row* - unclear

Comment: Well, you can make `grep` search for a pattern only a specific column if you know how to define a column, e.g. `seq 10 | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -E '^([^ ]+ ){6}7'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FNR` (FNR means file number of record) to print the row number and `FILENAME` to print the file's name, then you get the matching lines from which file and which row, for instance:

sample.csv:

```
aaa 123
bbb 456
aaa 789
```

command:

```
awk '$1 =="aaa"{print $0, FNR, FILENAME}' sample.csv
```

The output is:

```
aaa 123 1 sample.csv
aaa 789 3 sample.csv
```

Comment: @karakfa Thanks, forgot to change it!  it was a typo, I had only one column in my sample.csv, I added the numeric values column to make my post clear

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for:

```
awk '$7 == "GENENAME"{print FILENAME, $0}' FOLDER/*
```

If not then edit your question to clarify with sample input and expected output.